# Open Specific Directory Using Storage Access Framework

Tags: android, android-intent, android-5.0-lollipop, storage-access-framework

I'm currently able to obtain a file URI by opening the Lollipop file picker using the code below:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
            startActivity(intent);
```

The file picker opens either at the root of Internal Storage or the last directory that I opened. **How can I make the file picker show the contents of a specific directory?** For example, I might want the file picker to show the contents of the Download folder after launching like in the picture below.

[image: opened subdirectory]

Comment: you have found a solution?

Comment: @VadimStar not yet :(. I haven't been actively developing for Android recently, though.

Answer (score -2):

Use the **Environment** class which has methods like `getExternalStorageDirectory()` or `getDataDirectory()`
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html.

If the images are stored in a variable, grab them from that path:

```
private static final String fileName = Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            + "/pathToFile.jpg";
```

Comment: `getExternalStorageDirectory()` has been deprecated.